# Cumulative sum of values by month

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, cumulative-sum

I'm doing a query in SQL Server and I get an error

> Incorrect Syntax near 'order'

I already saw several questions about it and did the revision of the code but I could not see where I am going wrong.

This is the query:

```
SELECT  
    datepart(month, nota.DT_Sale_Forma_Bill_Exit) AS mon_text,
    sum(SUM(nota.NM_Material)) OVER (ORDER BY datepart(month,nota.DT_Sale_Forma_Bill_Exit)) 
FROM
    DW_DTS_Representative usuario
INNER JOIN 
    DIS_DTS_Invoice_Fact nota ON usuario.SK_Representative =  nota.SK_Representative
INNER JOIN
    DW_DTS_Operation_Nature cfop ON cfop.SK_Operation_Nature = nota.SK_Operation_Nature
INNER JOIN
    DW_DTS_Emitter cli ON cli.SK_Emitter = nota.SK_Emitter
WHERE
    nota.CD_Currency = '1'
    AND nota.CD_Site = '001'
    AND nota.DT_Sale_Forma_Bill_Exit = '2017'
    AND cli.CD_Customer_Group != '16'
GROUP BY 
    datepart(month, nota.DT_Sale_Forma_Bill_Exit)
ORDER BY 
    datepart(month, nota.DT_Sale_Forma_Bill_Exit)
```

Comment: This was not introduced until SQL Server 2012.

Comment: But the Microsoft website says it's for versions starting in 2008.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql

Comment: The over clause was introduced in 2005 but didn't support order by with aggregates until 2012.